# How to access to the demo dashboard shown on the Developers' week held on Brussels

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

During the last day presentation regarding the IoT infrastructure in Brussels Pullman hotel you demonstrated a certain dashboard/app for smart cities using WireCloud.

Is there a possibility to get the source code for said application so that we may fiddle with it and ultimately deploy it locally in order to better understand how FIWARE technologies work?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Francisco (who presented WireCloud at the Developers' Weeks @ Brussels) did not show any example about Santander (but there is a demo based on Santander). Are you referring to the dashboard shown on the slide 7 of this presentation: http://www.slideshare.net/mjimenezganan/wirecloud-presentation ?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that dashboard installing the [CKANStarterKit offering](https://store.lab.fiware.org/offering/CoNWeT/CKANStarterKit/1.2). Concretely, the dashboard is provided by the "CKAN Valencia with cameras mashup" resource. Once installed, you can create a new workspace using this mashup as template.

This mashup uses the following widgets and operators:

- [MapViewer](https://github.com/Wirecloud/map-viewer-widget) widget
- Input Box widget
- [Web Browser](https://github.com/Wirecloud/web-browser-widget) widget
- Filter POI data operator

> **NOTE:** Currently not all of those widgets/operators are in github, but I'm creating them, I will update this answer with the links. In the meantime you can download the widgets/operators using the user interface:
>   [image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, in the meanwhile I figured out how to deploy this in the mashup, allthough I dont have any camera views available.

But my current interest is the source code, so that we may fiddle with it to make our own application for our accelerator.

Comment: You have to click on a webcamera poi icon for accessing the webcamera stream.

Comment: Excellent, now if only there were some way to get that source code of that widget or some other which is similar?

Comment: You can access to the source code of the widget opening the downloaded .wgt files. You can open/extract wgt files using any zip tool.
You have more example widgets/operators repositories [here](https://github.com/Wirecloud) and [here](https://github.com/wirecloud-fiware)